# How to get generic json string from Azure search SearchClient

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I am using azure search SDK SearchClient to query documents from index. To use the SearchClient.Search(), method, I must firstly defined a type T for my index document.
For example

`searchClient.Search<Hotel>("*", options);`

Is it possible just let SearchClient.Search return general Json string so that I can parse it with my own code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a specific type, you can use [`SearchDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.search.documents.models.searchdocument?view=azure-dotnet) which represents an untyped document returned from a search or document lookup. It can be accessed as either a dynamic object or a dictionary.

So your code would be:

```
searchClient.Search<SearchDocument>("*", options);
```

From this [`link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.search.documents.searchclient.search?view=azure-dotnet#remarks):

> Search and SearchAsync methods support mapping of search field types
> to .NET types via the type parameter T. **You can provide your own type
> T or use the dynamic SearchDocument**.